# Accessing model fields in Django html template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to print fields from my 'Assignment' class, but nothing I try seems to work. In the html template I am trying to print the 'assignment_title'. Here are all my files to help show where I am up to

urls.py

```
url(r'^feedback/$', views.assignment, name='assignments')
```

models.py

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
assignment_title = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
lecturer = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

views.py

```
# Assignment view
def assignment(request):
args = {'assignment': Assignment}
return render(request, 'mainfocus/feedback.html', args)
```

html

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Feedback</h1>
<p>{{ obj.assignment_title }}</p>
</div>
```

Just to confirm, I have registered the class in 'admin.py' as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have also migrated and populated the tables so that should not be a problem either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANSWER!

views.py

```
# Assignment view
def assignment(request):
    assignments = Assignment.objects.all()
    args = {
        'assignments': assignments
    }
    return render(request, 'mainfocus/feedback.html', args)
```

models.py

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
    lecturer = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

html

```
    {% for assignment in assignments %}
        <p>{{ assignment.title }}</p>
    {% empty %}
        <p>No assignments available</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `obj` in `views.py` contains all of your `Assignment` from the database. If you want to print only one Assignment, then you should filter them:

```py
# Assignment view
def assignment(request):
  obj = Assignment.objects.first() # get the first assignment for example
  return render(request, 'mainfocus/feedback.html',{'obj': obj})
```

If you want to print all of them, then you should modify your template to use a [for loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>Feedback</h1>
{% for assignment in obj %}
<p>{{ assignment.assignment_title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my views.py now, do I still need a for loop?

Comment: If you want to print all of them, then just modify the template with a for loop.

Comment: This isn't true. `Assignment` by itself doesn't give you access to all the items; you would need to do `Assignment.objects.all()`.

Comment: I have updated the answer at the bottom, thanks for your input!